# Google BigQuery Incomplete Query Replies on Odd Attempts

Tags: python, google-bigquery, google-api-python-client

When querying BigQuery through the python api using:

```
service.jobs().getQueryResults
```

We're finding that the first attempt works fine - all expected results are included in the response. However, if the query is run a second time shortly after the first (roughly within 5 minutes) only a small subset of the results are returned (in powers of 2) nearly instantly, with no errors.

See our complete code at:
https://github.com/sean-schaefer/pandas/blob/master/pandas/io/gbq.py

Any thoughts on what could cause this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the issue is that we return different default numbers of rows for query() and getQueryResults(). So depending on whether your query finished quickly (and so you didn't have to use getQueryResults()) you'd either get more or less rows.

I've filed a bug and we should have a fix soon.

The workaround (and a good idea overall) is to set the maxResults for both the query and the getQueryResults calls. And if you're going to want a lot of rows, you might want to page through results using the returned page token.

Below is an example that reads one page of data from a completed query job. It will be included in the next release of bq.py:

```
class _JobTableReader(_TableReader):
  """A TableReader that reads from a completed job."""

  def __init__(self, local_apiclient, project_id, job_id):
    self.job_id = job_id
    self.project_id = project_id
    self._apiclient = local_apiclient

  def ReadSchemaAndRows(self, max_rows=None):
    """Read at most max_rows rows from a table and the schema.

    Args:
      max_rows: maximum number of rows to return.

    Raises:
      BigqueryInterfaceError: when bigquery returns something unexpected.

    Returns:
      A tuple where the first item is the list of fields and the
      second item a list of rows.
    """
    page_token = None
    rows = []
    schema = {}
    max_rows = max_rows if max_rows is not None else sys.maxint
    while len(rows) < max_rows:
      (more_rows, page_token, total_rows, current_schema) = self._ReadOnePage(
          max_rows=max_rows - len(rows),
          page_token=page_token)
      if not schema and current_schema:
        schema = current_schema.get('fields', {})

      max_rows = min(max_rows, total_rows)
      for row in more_rows:
        rows.append([entry.get('v', '') for entry in row.get('f', [])])
      if not page_token and len(rows) != max_rows:
          raise BigqueryInterfaceError(
            'PageToken missing for %r' % (self,))
      if not more_rows and len(rows) != max_rows:
        raise BigqueryInterfaceError(
            'Not enough rows returned by server for %r' % (self,))
    return (schema, rows)

  def _ReadOnePage(self, max_rows, page_token=None):
    data = self._apiclient.jobs().getQueryResults(
        maxResults=max_rows,
        pageToken=page_token,
        # Sets the timeout to 0 because we assume the table is already ready.
        timeoutMs=0,
        projectId=self.project_id,
        jobId=self.job_id).execute()
    if not data['jobComplete']:
      raise BigqueryError('Job %s is not done' % (self,))
    page_token = data.get('pageToken', None)
    total_rows = int(data['totalRows'])
    schema = data.get('schema', None)
    rows = data.get('rows', [])
    return (rows, page_token, total_rows, schema)
```

Comment: Do you have an example for using the page token? We found the documentation page: https://developers.google.com/bigquery/docs/data#paging , but it didn't have any code samples. This seems important for our code since there is a hard cap on maximum results per page.

Comment: Also, is this an API bug, or a backend bug? We seem to still be having it, so will we need to pull a newer version once this is completed?

Comment: The fix is entirely on the BigQuery backend. It should have gone live yesterday.

Comment: If you're still seeing unexpected behavior, can you give the job ids of the queries?

Comment: It seemed like we were still having the issue yesterday, though at present we don't output job ids. We can make the change and get back to you on this. In the meantime, we're still interested in if there's any examples floating around for using paging in python.

Comment: As a followup, we haven't been able to identify any job id's that caused problems. We also started a couple of Feature requests on BigQuery, but it doesn't seem that it gets very much attention. Is there a better place to put these? In particular, we still would like to see a Python example for pagination:

http://code.google.com/p/google-bigquery/issues/detail?id=32

Comment: I've added a python paging example to my response.

Comment: Sorry it's been a while - another project we were working on took priority. You said this was going to be included in the bq.py project (presumably under bigquery_client.py) - will this be in addition to the existing BigqueryClient.ReadTableRows() method, or will the functionality be replaced? Also, any idea when the next release will be? In light of a significant number of API troubles we've had, we're considering altering our pandas module to simply extend bq.py. One trouble we're having is that the ReadTableRows() doesn't seem to have any batching capabilities, and neither does BigQuery SQL

Comment: BigQuery does support batching of API requests (although not necessarily batching SQL statements). The raw support is described here: https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/how-tos/batch. I can post a python sample, but it is too long for this comment block -- if you are interested, ask another top-level question?

Comment: Well, I didn't mean that kind of batching - I meant like in MySQL "SELECT {x} LIMIT {start}, {finish}" where you can increment {start},{finish}. Also, I tried working with your code example and I'm not having much luck. I am consistently getting:

"TypeError: Got an unexpected keyword argument "pageToken""

When I try to define 'data' as you did in your example. I also noticed that your class implements '_TableReader', which I can't find in the current API.

Comment: The pageToken argument should be available in jobs.getQueryResults(). See the pydoc here: https://google-api-client-libraries.appspot.com/documentation/bigquery/v2/python/latest/bigquery_v2.jobs.html#getQueryResults

Comment: I really hate to resurrect an old thread like this, but we are having similar issues in this thread:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19145587/bq-py-not-paging-results
We had some initial feedback from someone named Eric, but we have not heard back since. These are ultimately both related to paging, so maybe you could take a look? 

Again, I really don't like to use Stack in this way, but per
https://developers.google.com/bigquery/support
This is your official support portal.

Comment: Eric is on the BigQuery team. My understanding is that he is releasing a new version of bq.py that fixes the issue. I'll follow up with him and ask him to update the other question.