# bq.py Not Paging Results

Tags: python, google-bigquery, google-api-python-client

We're working on writing a wrapper for [bq.py](https://developers.google.com/bigquery/bq-command-line-tool) and are having some problems with result sets larger than 100k rows. It seems like in the past this has worked fine (we had related problems with [Google BigQuery Incomplete Query Replies on Odd Attempts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17751944/google-bigquery-incomplete-query-replies-on-odd-attempts)). Perhaps I'm not understanding the limits explained on the [doc page](https://developers.google.com/bigquery/docs/data)?

For instance:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

for i in `seq 99999 100002`;
do
    bq query -q --nouse_cache --max_rows 99999999 "SELECT id, FROM [publicdata:samples.wikipedia] LIMIT $i" > $i.txt
    j=$(cat $i.txt | wc -l)
    echo "Limit $i Returned $j Rows"
done
```

Yields (note there are 4 lines of formatting):

```
Limit 99999 Returned   100003 Rows
Limit 100000 Returned   100004 Rows
Limit 100001 Returned   100004 Rows
Limit 100002 Returned   100004 Rows
```

In our wrapper, we directly access the API:

```python
while row_count < total_rows:
    data = client.apiclient.tabledata().list(maxResults=total_rows - row_count,
                                                 pageToken=page_token,
                                                 **table_dict).execute()

    # If there are more results than will fit on a page, 
    # you will recieve a token for the next page
    page_token = data.get('pageToken', None)

    # How many rows are there across all pages?
    total_rows = min(total_rows, int(data['totalRows'])) # Changed to use get(data[rows],0)
    raw_page = data.get('rows', [])
```

We would expect to get a token in this case, but none is returned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sorry it took me a little while to get back to you.

I was able to identify a bug that exists server-side, you would end up seeing this with the Java client as well as the python client. We're planning on pushing a fix out this coming week. Your client should start to behave correctly as soon as that happens.

BTW, I'm not sure if you knew this already or not but there's a whole standalone python client that you can use to access the API from python as well. I thought that might be a bit more convenient for you than the client that's distributed as part of bq.py. You'll find a link to it on this page:
https://developers.google.com/bigquery/client-libraries

Comment: Thanks for the information - we are looking forward to the change. We are aware of the API clients and originally used it exclusively. However, we encountered numerous problems, some due to API changes that forced us to consider alternatives. bq.py implements nearly all the functionality we need, and I'm a big fan of reusing tested code whenever possible. Also, the built-in authentication flow code is a lot smoother than what I could have come up with :-)

Please let us know when the changes are live.

Comment: Hey Jacob,

  Give it a shot now and let me know if you are still having a problem.

Comment: Was this a backend change, or will I need to do something different? The demonstration script I gave above generates the same incorrect results. Likewise, our wrapper around the code still fails for similar queries.

Comment: Hey Jacob, 

  It was a server-side change on our end, we deployed earlier this week. I ran your reproduction and I'm seeing the right number of rows come back (100003, 100004, 100005, 100006).

  I'm using the same client I was using when I first ran your reproduction case and I got the same result you did at that time (100003, 100004, 100004, 100004).

  You could try the latest client, just to rule out the possibility it somehow is involved in the behavior you're seeing.

Comment: Something in the old client (2.0.15) is preventing the fix from helping... I haven't investigate further, but it seems that the issue persists unless I upgrade to 2.0.16 (`easy_install --upgrade bigquery`). We'll try some real queries and verify further... I'm curious to know what changed, since we had it working on 2.0.15 a few weeks ago, then it stopped working for all releases, and now it works only for 2.0.16.

Comment: Sorry about that, Jacob. It seems like there were also some changes in the client that didn't handle the max_row limit correctly. I'm adding some more tests around this case to make sure we don't break you again.

Answer (score 1):

I can reproduce the behavior you're seeing with the bq command-line. That seems like a bug, I'll see what I can do to fix it.

One thing I did notice about the data you're querying was that selecting the id field only, and capping the number of rows around 100,000. This produces about ~1M worth of data so the server would likely not paginate the results. Selecting a larger amount of data will force the server to paginate since it will not be able to return all the results in a single response. If you did a select * for 100,000 rows of samples.wikipedia you'd be getting ~50M back which should be enough to start to see some pagination happen.

Are you seeing too few results come back from the python client as well or were you surprised that no page_token was returned for your samples.wikipedia query?

Comment: Both actually - I was under the impression that pagination was based on row size rather than raw data size. The documentation is rather confusing on this subject, in particular when pagination kicks in and what the maximum paged result set is. Regardless, we are still getting too few rows in both bq.py directly and our code which calls the API directly (using bq.py as a driver).

Comment: Is there a timeline for this fix? It is a serious limitation for our current workflow. It appears to be an API issue, which I would expect is affecting other clients as well.

Comment: Is this problem affecting the Java API client as well? We have some analyses that are at a bit of a stand-still, and we're looking for some workaround. Will this require a change in the client code? We're getting ready to push a connector module into production, and we need to be sure the dependency requirements are fine.